# React Material-UI pickers how to convert moment object and set state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

I'm a react beginner and trying my luck with Material-UI picker.

The props in console.log are a moment object.
Now i would like to convert the moment object to a regular date format and update the **state** prop **date** with it but i have no idea how do this. Especially after too many guides, try end error ^^
Thanks for your time

```
class EventFormMaterial extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: ""
    };

handleDateChange(props) {
setState({}) ...
  }

return (
  <div className="flex-second-container">
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
            <DateTimePicker
              variant="inline"
              label="Basic example"
              value={this.state.selectedDate}
              onChange={this.handleDateChange}
              format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`handleDateChange = date => {
    setState({ date: date.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') })
}`

If date is a moment object, you can format it and set the new state on handleDateChange method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. If i review this i would say my main prow was that i forgot to bind the function after the classconstructor an always had errormessages which i understood completely wrong. Alwas thought i set my state in the wrong way. After your answer i knew i was right and searched for the real issues.

Comment: Good to know that helped you :)

Comment: It is not really a good way to solve the problem. This format step is not required, you can just pass the `date` right to your state.

Answer (score 0):

Simple put returned date object right to the state

```
state = { date: moment() } 

handleDateChange = (newDate) => { 
  this.setState({ date: newDate })
} 

<DatePicker
  value={this.state.date}
  onChange={this.handleDateChange} 
/>
```

With no additional work.